# GenericForeinKey retrieve field value in models.py

Tags: django

I am trying to retrieve a field from a GenericForeignKey and cannot make it work in the model.py - it works in the admin.py though.

models.py:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TaskRunRelation(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q(app_label = 'thisapp', model = 'run') | models.Q(app_label = 'thisapp', model = 'runb')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def modeltestname(self):
        self.content_object.name
```

admin.py:

```
class TaskRelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['modeltestname','mytestname']
    def mytestname(self,obj):
        return obj.content_object.name
```

So mytestname shows the correct value in the Admin whereas modeltestname shows "(None)". Why is this not working in the model.py? Am I missing something how Genericforeignkey works or is there any other mistake in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not *returning* anything from `modeltestname`. If a function or method does not return anything explictly, it would return `None` by default. Hence the result

So change the class method to

```
def modeltestname(self):
    return self.content_object.name
```